# Importing Cassandra 2.2 schema to a 4.1 cluster returns SyntaxException: "Unknown property 'dclocal_read_repair_chance'"

Tags: cassandra

I'm using CentOS and import via command:

```
$ cqlsh -e "SOURCE '...'"
```

I got an error:

```
SyntaxException: Unknown property 'dclocal_read_repair_chance'
```

when imported schema_db from old version 2.2 to new version 4.1.2.

Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Background repair was deprecated in Cassandra 3.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/NEWS.txt#L157-L159) and [3.11](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt#L204-L208), and [completely removed in Cassandra 4.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/NEWS.txt#L336-L338) ([CASSANDRA-13910](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13910)). This means that the table options `read_repair_chance` and `dclocal_read_repair_chance` are no longer valid and cannot be used in C* 4.x.

You will need to manually modify the source CQL file you are using to create the schema in C* 4.1 and remove the deprecated table options then try again.

Given the large jump in versions, I highly recommend that you review the upgrade steps in [`NEWS.txt` for C* 3.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/NEWS.txt), [3.11](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11/NEWS.txt), [4.0](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0/NEWS.txt) and [4.1](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.1/NEWS.txt) so you have a good idea of the issues you could possibly run into. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I just got it from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13910. 
Thank you